# Does user feedback always get worse over time as a website gets older?

Tags: feedback, user-feedback

We use 'Is this useful? Yes / No' feedback. We have targets from senior management to improve feedback results, but they are not getting better, no matter how many UX and content improvements we make and errors we avoid.

I've also noticed that visitors are less and less likely to submit feedback as time goes on.

So, is this just a rule for websites as they get older - does feedback worsen over time? My theory is that when the website was new, people were keen to provide their feedback – but once they had done so once, there was no reason for them to do so again, and so over time the feedback becomes biased towards those who just want to complain.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the Kano Model + basic expectations, best discussed by Jared Spool [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewpz2gR_oJQ), [here](https://vimeo.com/140302789), and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hr1rN3jibIk).  It will be the unifying theory as to what happens to a website over time.  Slightly dated examples BUT the foundation is unbelievable useful

But also take into consideration that Craigslist is HIGHLY FUNCTIONAL, but the aesthetic is barebones.  So make sure that there isn't confusion between aesthetics and usability improvements.